# How do I use a PWM unit and/or microcontroller to have transistors progressively all turn on and then progressively all switch off?

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, pwm

How do I use a PWM unit and/or microcontroller to have transistors progressively all turn on and then progressively all switch off? It's for what will most likely be an 18-pulse inverter.

Essentially, I'll have 18 transistors (2 rows of 9) and I'll want the top row to come on progressively, then the bottom row, then I'll want the top row to switch off progressively followed by the bottom row. That being one cycle, I'll need to have that happen 60 times per second.

I think I can use a PWM/motor controller to do this and/or a microcontroller, but not sure where to look to firmly understand the schematic.

Answer (score 3):

Just do it in a periodic interrupt.  It appears you have up to 36 events 60 times per second, for a total event freuency of 2.76 kHz.  That's still "low" for many processors.  Even just a 10 MIPS processor will execute 3600 instructions per interrupt.  What you want to do will take nowhere near that.

You can even accomodate the 36 events per cycle being somewhat unevenly space in time.  Using the same 10 MIPS processor for example, you could set up the interrupt every 600 cycles (60 µs).  That's still way more cycles than it takes to figure out what phase you're in and change the appropriate output accordingly.  But this interrupt is now 6 times faster than your events occur on average, so you have extra resolution in placing event within a cycle.  And that was only interrupting every 600 cycles on a slow processor.

Somewhat of a aside, but it sounds like you're trying to make 60 Hz power the hard way.  Are these transistors each driving a separate tap of a transformer primary?  That should work, but will be rather expensive and bulky compared to a more common solution like a class D drive with the PWM duty cycle adjusted each cycle to result in the 60 Hz sine output.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so I'm not surprised I've overcomplicated things! In essence, I'm wanting to take DC at a given voltage (a high one at that) into 60Hz AC. From reading I've done since I've posted this question, I think insulated-gate bipolar transistors would be best for this (preferably with 12, 18 or 24 pulses to make a smooth sine wave). Am I on the right track with that? If so, how best to control the IGBTs or thyristors (if thyristors are more appropriate than IGBTs)? Cheers

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with what a Class D drive is. Are these modules that I can just purchase as per frequency requirements (I.e. 36 x 60, as per above)? I won't necessarily have a fixed DC input either as, essentially, I'm transforming down a varying AC high voltage signal, rectifying the wave to DC, then inverting back fixed at 50Hz

Comment: @Chris: If you're not familiar with class D, then you should start by learning that.  That's how inverters are typically done, for good reason.  Teaching class D would be too much for here, but surely there is much out there on it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can use shift registers. The idea is driving it all 1s and than 0s with just a data and clock pin. Serially connected 3 of 74hc164s would fit for that.

You can use PWM for clock and interrupt for data state.